# (cocos2d-x for iOS) UITextField would crash some times when input

Tags: crash, uitextfield, cocos2d-x

I had add UITextField in my cocos2d-x project.but when input,the app will crash some times.
please give me some help,thanks.
this is my code

```
   m_textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(TEXT_FIELD_POSX, TEXT_FIELD_POSY, TEXT_FIELD_WIDTH, TEXT_FILED_HEIGHT)];
    m_textField.tag = CHAT_TEXT_TAG;
    m_textField.delegate = (AppController *)clientApp.delegate;
    [m_textField setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [m_textField setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    [m_textField setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:14]];
    m_textField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeySend;
    m_textField.enablesReturnKeyAutomatically = YES;

    [[EAGLView sharedEGLView] addSubview:m_textField];
```

and the crash thread`0

```
CoreGraphics 0x31e09fcc CGFontStrikeRelease + 71
1   
CoreGraphics 0x31e09f0b CGFontCacheUnlockStrike + 230
2   
CoreGraphics 0x31e09a89 CGGlyphLockUnlock + 52
3   
libRIP.A.dylib 0x34604acd ripc_DrawGlyphs + 1888
4   
CoreGraphics 0x31e05361 CGContextDelegateDrawGlyphs + 44
5   
CoreGraphics 0x31ee530d draw_glyphs + 396
6   
CoreGraphics 0x31e05109 CGContextShowGlyphsWithAdvances + 380
7   
WebCore 0x3664552b _ZN7WebCoreL22showGlyphsWithAdvancesERKNS_10FloatPointEPKNS_14SimpleFontDataEP9CGContextPKtPK6CGSizem + 1918
8   
WebCore 0x36644c8f _ZNK7WebCore4Font10drawGlyphsEPNS_15GraphicsContextEPKNS_14SimpleFontDataERKNS_11GlyphBufferEiiRKNS_10FloatPointEb + 1078
9   
WebCore 0x36644525 _ZNK7WebCore4Font14drawSimpleTextEPNS_15GraphicsContextERKNS_7TextRunERKNS_10FloatPointEii + 348
10  
WebCore 0x366443a3 _ZNK7WebCore4Font8drawTextEPNS_15GraphicsContextERKNS_7TextRunERKNS_10FloatPointEii + 134
11  
WebKit 0x34fd86ef _ZL11drawAtPointPKtiRKN7WebCore10FloatPointERKNS1_4FontEPNS1_15GraphicsContextEbPNS1_10BidiStatusEi + 210
12  
WebKit 0x34fda56b -[NSString(WebStringDrawing) __web_drawInRect:withFont:ellipsis:alignment:letterSpacing:lineSpacing:includeEmoji:truncationRect:measureOnly:renderedStringOut:drawUnderline:] + 3690
13  
WebKit 0x34f52187 -[NSString(WebStringDrawing) __web_drawInRect:withFont:ellipsis:alignment:letterSpacing:lineSpacing:includeEmoji:truncationRect:measureOnly:renderedStringOut:] + 114`
```

Comment: @webduos.com help me...when i type character,my app will crash.

Comment: Weird thing. Where and how did you  implemente UITextFieldDelegate methods?

Comment: @SpencerWong UITextFieldDelegate methods is in a "AppController.mm" class,and have the two methods: textFieldShouldReturn,textFieldDidEndEditing

Comment: I have the similar situation and my textfield doesn't call any its delegate methods. Or the app crashes on delegate assigning but I don't know how to solve it

Answer (score 0):

You should implement your delegate methods like this:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    cocos2d::CCEGLView* pglview = cocos2d::CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getOpenGLView();
    if(pglview)
    {
        pglview->setIMEKeyboardState(false);
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Hope it will help :) .

Comment: i am come from china.add me qq:763278787

Comment: the crash happen in inputing.no at click "return".

Comment: crash when typing text into UITextField